# Partner User unable to view a record despite sharing it with him

Tags: apex, community, opportunity, sharing, partner-communities

I have set up a partner community where users with "Partner Community" license can create opportunities. The owner of the opportunity record changes over time and the record is made accessible to the creator via creation of share records using a flow. Currently, the community users are able to create the record but they're unable to view it when the owner is changed. It shows me "Page not available" error.

[image]

I can see the record is shared with the community user by clicking on "sharing" button on the record detail page but the community user is unable to view the record

[image: sharing screenshot]

Additionally I have checked the accessibility of the record type at profile, field level securities of the record and everything is provided to the user appropriately. He is able to create the record and work on it as long as he is the owner of the record.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the audiences set up for the page. I had set up page variations for different audiences based on the values on the record. There was no default page set if the record met none of the criteria. Setting up a default page fixed the problem.